# How to JS Strings and Vars for complete begginer

Tags: javascript, string, variables

Im learning JS programming but Im completely new and not familliar with terms and usage yet. Im coding macros and I want to substitute STRVALUE for var V1.

Can someone hint how to use variables in getString?

Its meant to run SCRIPT1 upon detecting XXX in chat, but Im adding alot of possible scripts.
I would love to combine two or more variables instead of STRVAL. something like
STRVAL== "V1 + V2 or V3"

```
var V1 = XXX
var V2 = Y
var V3 = Z

if (event.text.getString() == "STRVAL")
JsMacros.runScript("SCRIPT1.js")
```

Im running different Scripts depending on String output and I have to include STRVAL for each if statement, after every runScript like

```
if (event.text.getString() == "STRVAL1")
JsMacros.runScript("SCRIPT1.js")

if (event.text.getString() == "STRVAL2")
JsMacros.runScript("SCRIPT2.js")

if (event.text.getString() == "STRVAL3")
JsMacros.runScript("SCRIPT3.js")
```

I would like to use shortcut ID's of Variables just including on top.

```
var V1 = XXX
var V2 = Y
var V3 = Z
```

Thanks for help, as I said Im really green with JS yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all string variables are diclared with cotes ("" or '')
so when declaring the V1,V2 and V3 you should write :

```
var V1 = 'XXX'
var V2 = 'Y'
var V3 = 'Z'
```

now for if statement i belive you need to know how **includes()** works
it returns a boolean variable that determines if a string contains another string

eg:

```
"Hello word".includes("word")
 > true
```

so it's perfect for you case like so :

```
var V1 = 'XXX'
var V2 = 'Y'
var V3 = 'Z'
if (event.text.getString().includes(V1 + V2))
    JsMacros.runScript("SCRIPT1.js")
```

or with arrays (it's pretty much the same)

```
if ([V1 + V2 , V3].includes(event.text.getString()))
    JsMacros.runScript("SCRIPT1.js")
```

Good luck learning Js

Comment: Thanks alot, now it make's sense!